# Timeout value for TLS/DTLS heartbeat extension

Tags: ssl, heartbeat, dtls

What exactly timeout value for TLS(DTLS) heartbeat extension? What I understand is that TLS(DTLS) Heartbeat extension is to check liveliness between server and client like keep-alive. That means, sender sends periodically heartbeat request and receiver should response heartbeat response to sender. But, there is no definition of timeout value in RFC 6520. How to set the timeout value up to implement this functionality?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about the protocol rather than the implementation; ask on IT Security (next time).